# keydown event in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to create a Drop down list, that when a user holds the SHIFT key, it will select the same index on all other drop down lists.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function (e) { shifted = e.shiftKey });
$(document).on('change', '.report_info select', function (e) {
    if (shifted) {
        //Code to change other drop down lists.
    }
});
```

This only works if you press and hold the shift key before you enter the drop down list.  If you are inside the DDL and press the shift key, the keyup/keydown event will not fire and `shifted` will remain `false`

**Is there any way to catch the keyup/keydown event while a dropdownlist is focused?**

**Edit:**

Looks like it might be an issue with **Chrome** only, Just tried adding the following, and it works in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome:

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'select', function (e) {
    shifted = e.shiftKey;
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it not working in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ue6xqm1q/4

Comment: have you tried adding the trigger to <select>? $("select").on(...)

Comment: above code is working on chromium. use jquery blur. this might solve your problem

Comment: Do you know where the bug on the chrome issue tracker is by any chance?

Comment: I never reported it as a bug, not sure if there exists one or not.

Answer (score 12):

I think @judgeja's response may be your best bet.  I'm posting this as an "answer" instead of a comment, because I've done my own research to determine that absolutely no event gets fired when a `select` element is open in Chrome.

See Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m4tndtu4/6/

I've attached all possible event handlers (I think) to the `input` element and both `select` elements.

In Chrome, you'll see many events fire when working with the `input` element, but you'll see no events fire when working in the first `select` element when it is open.

Interestingly, events *do* fire in Chrome if the `select` element has the `multiple` attribute or `size`>1.

In Firefox, you'll see events firing on all three elements.

Outside @judgeja's suggestion, your best bet may be to simulate the `select` element.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

*Warning: Chrome (mis)behavior differs on different platforms! In Chrome Windows a keydown event is triggered right after the select is released, while on OsX it is not. This explains why @judgeja solution worked for some, and didn't for me, while mine worked on OsX and not on Windows.*

So I created an updated fiddle to merge my OsX solution with his Windows one.

http://jsfiddle.net/0fz5vcq6/5/

On platforms where the keydown is triggered uses @judgeja solution, if it is not triggered it tests for a keyup event without the previous keydown (my previous solution). It is ugly as it works only after RELEASE of the shift key, but ugly only on Chrome OsX.

```
var shifted = false;
var hackytimer = 0;
var lastval=null;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 16){
        if(Date.now() - hackytimer <200){
            alert("you pressed shift inside the select (Win)");
           changeAllSelects($(this).val());
       }        shifted = true;
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 16) {
        if(!shifted && lastval!=null) {

            alert("you pressed shift inside the select (OsX)");
            $('.report_info select').each(function () {
                changeAllSelects(lastval);
            });

        }
        shifted = false;
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '.report_info select', function (e) {
    hackytimer = Date.now();        
    if (shifted) {
        changeAllSelects($(this).val());
    } else {
        lastval=$(this).val();
    }
});

function changeAllSelects(cr){
    hackytimer = 0;
    $('.report_info select').each(function () {
        $(this).val(cr);
    });
}
```

Credit goes mainly to @judgeja for his timer solution with some added workaround for the Mac (and other platforms that behave the same)

I still think emulating the selects with something HTML like http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ is cleaner as they should not interfere with keydown/keyups.

**PREVIOUS SOLUTION (OsX only)**

The only solution I could think of, in the total absence of any event, is to test if a shift up occurred without the previous shift down. This may work if you don't have other elements that behave the same way as the selects

http://jsfiddle.net/6jkkgx5e/

It is a bit tricky and dirty, will work AFTER the user releases the shift key

```
var shifted = false;
var lastval=null;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 16){
        shifted = true;
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which == 16){
        if(!shifted && lastval!=null) {

            alert("you pressed shift inside the select");
            $('.report_info select').each(function () {
                $(this).val(lastval);
            });

        }
        shifted = false;
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '.report_info select', function (e) {
    var cr = $(this).val();
    if (shifted) {
        $('.report_info select').each(function () {
            $(this).val(cr);
        });
    } else {
        lastval=cr;
    }
});
```

Should behave normally on non buggy browsers. Anyway I agree emulating the selects with something HTML like http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ might be the cleaner way.

Comment: @judgeja Yes, Chrome 37.0.2062.120 OsX, can you specify how it is not working? (giving errors, not updating,...)

Comment: I'm using chrome 37.0.2062.120 m and it isn't working as the OP asked. If you click a dropdown list, then hold shift, then select an option, only the current dropdown list is changed.

Comment: @judgeja isn't the update (and alert) triggered when you *release* the shift key? Are you trying the fiddle or copied the code? What does the "m" in "37.0.2062.120 m" stand for?

Comment: Nope, it isn't triggered. I'm trying the fiddle. I have no idea what the m stands for, it's the up-to-date version for windows 8.

Comment: @judgeja Ok, apparently Chrome on Windows does trigger a keydown event after you release the select, that makes your solution work on Windows but not on Mac (and my test for keyup fail), while Chrome Os X does not, that makes my solution work on Mac but not on Windows. Merging the two would make it work on both.

Comment: wow, a little unusual for chrome to be the one that requires such messing about for consistency! Fair play anyway for getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: @judgeja indeed! That's why I hadn't even tested on other platforms!

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax looks incorrect.

```
$("#target").keydown(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```

Comment: The $(document).on(event,selector,function) works for dynamically added elements after the page has been loaded, which is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty hacky solution to be honest, but it's a means to an ends until you hopefully find something better.

Since the problem is chrome doesn't register the keydown/keyup events on the `select` elements until after the dropdownlist has disappeared, we need to either

**a)** figure out how to make the event fire (I've no idea)

or

**b)** check if our conditions were met in a different order.

Chrome will fire the shift keypress event after click, so we can simply check if click was pressed immediately before this event. Since other browsers behave more expectedly we'll also leave the previous code in place.

To do this we set a timer on the click event, and then when the shift event for the select is fired, if the click event timer was also just set we should run our code here so that chrome will fire it. We reset the timer then so that it isn't fired multiple times.

**NOTE**: if you press shift immediately after setting the values (within whatever limit from the click you specify), it will also set them all. I don't think this is unreasonable as it actually feels quite natural when it happens.

I used the following code:

```
var shifted = false;
var hackytimer = 0;

$(document).on('keyup keydown', function (e) { 
    shifted = e.shiftKey;
});

$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'select', function (e) {
    shifted = e.shiftKey;
    if(Date.now() - hackytimer <200){
        changeAllSelects($(this).val());
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '.report_info select', function (e) {
    hackytimer = Date.now();        
    if (shifted) {
        changeAllSelects($(this).val());
    }
});

function changeAllSelects(cr){
    hackytimer = 0;
    $('.report_info select').each(function () {
        $(this).val(cr);
    });
}
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/0fz5vcq6/2/

Answer (score 2):

First of all. You should pick an event to register. Don't register to keyup and keydown the same time. You give the browser a hard time, because they affect your end result. To see what I mean, just edit the plunk, add a keyup event. The end result behaves a little sloppy.

**keyup**: Event fired when a key is released on the keyboard.

**keydown**: Event fired when a key is pressed on the keyboard.

**keypress**: Event fired when a key is pressed on the keyboard.

They have their differences, better stick to one, I prefer for this example to use keydown, just plays better with me, you can use keyup.

**Edit**: A quick note. The keyup for my example doesn't play well, because it seems, change in the selectedIndex, comes first and then the binded event. On keydown, first the event fires, does it's work and then the selectedIndex changes. To play with keyup, the code below needs some modification, that means the step is not needed, when you use keyup

I have a plnkr demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Axj3Nl?p=preview).

I've tested it on IE10, Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. As you might expect, webkit browsers, don't fire the keydown/keyup/keypress event when a select list has focus. Reason unknown for me, at the moment. In Firefox works great. On IE works partially. So, in order to achieve your goal, custom code to the rescue! I just binded a change event to the document, i hear for kewdown and change. If the event type is change, then the workaround comes into play. Here some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown change', 'select', function(evt){
        var shiftKey = evt.shiftKey;
        var code = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

        //if it's a change event and i dont have any shiftKey or code
        //set the to a default value of true
        if(evt.type === 'change' && !shiftKey && !code){
          //special! only when change is fired
          shiftKey = true;
          code = true; 
        }

        //if shift key
        if(shiftKey && (code === 40 || code === 38 || code === true)){

          var target = $(evt.target);
          //if code is not true means it is not a change event, go ahead and set
          //a step value, else no step value
          var step = (code !== true) ? (code === 40) ? 1 : -1 : 0;
          var index = target[0].selectedIndex + step;

          //just to keep the lower and upper bound of the select list
          if(index < 0){
            index = 0;
          }else if(index >= target[0].length){
            index = target[0].length - 1;
          }

          //get all other select lists
          var allOtherSelects = target.closest('div').siblings('div').children('select');
          //foreach select list, set its selectedIndex
          $.each(allOtherSelects, function(i, el){
            el.selectedIndex = index;
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: I catch the keyup and keydown event because it changed the 'shifted' variable. If I only caught the keydown event, shifted would always be true.  In your example, I am seeing all the dropdownlists change regardless of whether SHIFT is held down or not.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it seems i didn't tested that scenario. I've tryied many solutions, but couldn't reach your target. Seems it is a browser issue. One workaround is to use my code above without the change event, but your lists won't change when you select an option and the list has focus ( aka the dropdown is visible ). Another workaround is to register for a click event on the list options and then change the other ones as well. This works only on webkit browsers. I have edited the plunker url on the post above. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome hack: You can set custom event for document. And firing this event when press the shift key inside the DDL. Jquery firing trigger can pass custom params.

Comment: The problem with this is that the change event for the DDL will run before the custom event: shifted.ddl.  see here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8vep3jn/ I could run the code that needs to be done in the custom event, but then for Firefox and IE it will run every time shift is pressed, instead of just on shift+click.

Comment: The updated one only works if you hold shift before going into the dropdown list.

Comment: @Bryan hmm. You can show me (not working) jsfiddle example of what you need? I think I'm not full or misunderstand you. But I'm want help you.

Comment: @Deep I added a fiddle to the end of the original question.  This works if you hold shift BEFORE opening the dropdownlist.  I am looking for a solution to having it work when you press shift AFTER you open the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1):

Check the working [JS FIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/yvnfe9p4/)

Try the following script for your scenario

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.shifted = false;
    $(document).on('keyup keydown', function (e) { shifted = e.shiftKey; });
    $(document).on('change', 'select.report_info', function (e) {
        var cr = $(this).val();
        if (shifted) {
            $('.report_info').each(function () {
                $(this).val(cr);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is different than what I tried, can you explain?

Comment: I just change the selector from **.report_info select** to **select.report_info** and it is working over chrome too. Try the fiddler [js fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/yvnfe9p4/)

Comment: Are you holding shift before clicking into the dropdown list? If so, that was working before.  I am trying to catch the shift event when the dropdownlist is expanded.

Comment: both of the scenarios are working in my case. have you tried the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvnfe9p4/)

Comment: I have, and i am still experiencing the issue.  I thought it might be a conflict with some extension, but I used a fresh install of chrome on Windows 7, and it still doesn't work.  What version and OS are you running?

Comment: i am using it over **chrome 37.0.2062.120 m**

Answer (score 1):

Bryan, 
you can try the following way to do this. I tested on Jsfiddle it working in your way If I got your question correctly.

```
 var shifted = false;
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function (e) { shifted = e.shiftKey; });

$("select").on('keyup keydown',  function (e) {
    shifted = e.shiftKey;  
});
    $('.report_info select').on('change',  function (e) {
        var cr = $(this).val();
        if (shifted) {
            $('.report_info select').each(function () {
                $(this).val(cr);
            });
        }
    });
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Is this actually working for other people that upvoted?  It isn't working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5fnht2t6/

Comment: Bryan,I just updated a line of code. So please try here and let me know if you are still having any issue..http://jsfiddle.net/5fnht2t6/1/

Comment: Bryan made it pretty clear his problem was only with chrome, and your fiddle has the same problem as the original in chrome..

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Chrome 37 OsX, so apparently there are different Chrome functionalities on different versions/platforms, so be careful to test a lot

Answer (score 1):

Hello that was not working because of no focus on your select which has keydown bound

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/t8fsuy33/

```
$('select').first().focus();
```

Comment: yes it does, I'm using Ubuntu 12 + Chrome 34.0.1847.116

Answer (score 1):

Hop this thing help you out.. :)

```
 var onkeydown = (function (ev) {
      var key;
      var isShift;
      if (window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode;
        isShift = window.event.shiftKey ? true : false;
      } else {
        key = ev.which;
        isShift = ev.shiftKey ? true : false;
      }
      if ( isShift ) {
        switch (key) {
          case 16: // ignore shift key
            break;
          default:
            alert(key);
            // do stuff here?
            break;
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a very unique solution to this issue specifically for Chrome.  It appears Chrome shifts outside the normal dom for select elements when they have focus so you never get the onkey(down|press|up) events to capture the keycode. However if the size of the select box is >1 then it works.  But anyone who wants an actual drop down box instead of what looks like a combo box can solve this issue with this code.  In my case I was trying to prevent the backspace key from going back to the previous browser page.

Javascript looks like this:

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 
          $('select').keypress(function(event) 
             { return cancelBackspace(event) });
        $('select').keydown(function(event) 
           { return cancelBackspace(event) });
       }); 

      function cancelBackspace(event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            return false;
          }
       }
```

Then HTML looks like this:

`<select id="coaacct" style="border:none;width:295px;" onclick="if (this.size){this.size=''}else{this.size='20'};">`

I use the onclick event to change the size of the select box to 20 if it has no size and change it back to nothing if it has a size.  This way it functions like a normal select dropdown but because it has a size greater than 1 when you are selecting the option it will detect keycodes.  I didn't see this answered adequately anywhere else so I thought I would share my solution.

Comment: Hi! with oracle jet and comboboxes (oj-combobox-one), and also with inputs (text and number) if we use the keydown it works perfectly! thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do things with a dropdown that are this granular, it's likely not worth it to use the native `<select>` element as-is. In this thread alone, numerous implementation differences are discussed, and there are plenty more that are outside the scope of this discussion but will also likely affect you. There are several JS libraries that can wrap this control, leaving it as-is on mobile (where the native control is actually needed) but emulating it on desktop, where the control doesn't really do much that can't be emulated in JS.

- [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp) - doesn't automatically wrap native control for mobile
- [dropdown.js](https://github.com/FezVrasta/dropdown.js)
- [dropdown.dot.js](http://rogerdudler.github.io/dropdown.dot.js/)