# GWT listbox open handler

Tags: java, events, gwt

When i add a KeyDownHandler on a listbox, it works fine when the listbox is 'close' but when the options are displayed, no one event are handle...

How can i get event when options are diplayed ?

Here i got the event when the listbox is focus and press keys
[image: working]

Not here [image: not working]

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Have you tried in other browsers? It might be [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336710). Also, please, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183715/keydown-event-in-drop-down-list).

Comment: It's that... Thank you
I must find another way to do that now ^^