# Select dropdown trigger on key click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on react and I am using Select component provided by the material. (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/). Upon opening the dropdown, if I press a key and there is an option that starts with that key, the corresponding option is automatically selected.
This is true for normal HTML select element too.
For Example - If available options are Mike, Robert, Julie, Casie and after opening dropdown I press key R on my keyboard, the selection jumps to Robert automatically
Is there any way I can prevent this behavior? I tried to add onKeyPress event to Select component but it is not getting fired.

Steps to reproduce:

1. go to https://material-ui.com/components/selects/
2. Open any of the dropdowns
3. Press key T
4. The option Ten automatically gets selected.

Comment: Have you read [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: @CalvinNunes Added link to reproduce. This isn't a bug but something to do with how select dropdown has been implemented. Unfortunately in my case, I can't find a way to prevent this.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid this, maybe this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183715/keydown-event-in-drop-down-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the event propagation from the `<MenuItem>` as follows

```
 <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem   onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem  onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem  onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```